# Error when calling Cognitive Face API

Tags: python-3.x, face-api

I have a problem with microsoft's vision cognitive api for face recognition when i run `python create_person.py user52`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "create_person.py", line 9, in <module>
    res = CF.person.create(personGroupId, str(sys.argv[1]))
  File ".../cognitive_face/person.py", line 74, in create
    return util.request('POST', url, json=json)
  File ".../cognitive_face/util.py", line 106, in request
    response.status_code, response.text)
cognitive_face.util.CognitiveFaceException: Error when calling Cognitive Face API:
    status_code: 404
    code: 404
    message: { "statusCode": 404, "message": "Resource not found" }
```

this is my create_person.py file

```
import sys
import cognitive_face as CF
from global_variables import personGroupId
import sqlite3

Key = 'b065632b79ac4d97a96d5781463d54b1'
CF.Key.set(Key)
if len(sys.argv) is not 1:
    res = CF.person.create(personGroupId, str(sys.argv[1]))
    print(res)
    extractId = str(sys.argv[1])[-2:]
    connect = sqlite3.connect("Face-DataBase")
    cmd = "SELECT * FROM Students WHERE ID = " + extractId
    cursor = connect.execute(cmd)
    isRecordExist = 0
    for row in cursor:                                                          # checking wheather the id exist or not
        isRecordExist = 1
    if isRecordExist == 1:                                                      # updating name and roll no
        connect.execute("UPDATE Students SET personID = ? WHERE ID = ?",(res['personId'], extractId))
    connect.commit()                                                            # commiting into the database
    connect.close()
    print ("Person ID successfully added to the database")
```

Thanks for your helping hands.

Answer (score 0):

First check that the `personGroupId` you are passing in actually exists. You can do so by issuing a GET to `/persongroups/:id`. Live demo [here](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f30395246/console).

If it exists, then most likely the region of your API key doesn't match the default one ([which is West US](https://github.com/Microsoft/Cognitive-Face-Python/blob/master/cognitive_face/util.py#L14)).

You can try adding this to your code:

```
BASE_URL = 'https://YOUR-REGION.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/'
CF.BaseUrl.set(BASE_URL)
```